# Fastest way to search for a text string in all files & directories (recursively), then output the directory and filename

Tags: windows, search, findstr

In my current script, i am using findstr (Windows) as follows:

```
findstr /s "string" C:\*.*
```

but this is extremely slow.
What is the fastest way to do this in Windows without using any additional software (e.g. python, c#, etc...).
Also, the files in the directories are constantly changing, so i'm unable to index the files and perform a search on the index.

The results need the full path and filename with the string match.
The full lines where the string matches need to be returned.
Only text based files need to be searched (e.g. xml, txt, etc...)

Comment: Post has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

A possible batch file for this task would be:

```
@echo off
cd /D C:\
del "%USERPROFILE%\SearchResults.txt" 2>nul
%SystemRoot%\system32\findstr.exe /I /S /C:"string" *.htm *.html *.txt *.xml >"%USERPROFILE%\SearchResults.tmp"
ren "%USERPROFILE%\SearchResults.tmp" "SearchResults.txt"
```

First the current directory is changed to root of drive C:.

Next a perhaps existing search results file from a previous run on desktop of current user is deleted.

Then `findstr` is executed to search for the string case-insensitive in the files specified with wildcards on the command line. More file extensions can be appended. There is no file extension for "all text files".

`findstr` prints for each found occurrence the name of the file and the found line to **stdout** which is redirected into a text file with file extension `tmp` to desktop of current user. It is not advisable to give the results file a file extension being specified also on command line of `findstr`.

Finally the created results file is renamed to change file extension from `tmp` to `txt`.

But searching for a string in thousands of files with writing all found lines with name of file into a results file needs time. On second run the tasks finishes already faster because Windows will have many files already loaded in cache and does not access a second time the storage media for those files not changed in the meantime.

BTW: A case-sensitive search done with removing `/I` is much faster than a case-insensitive search.